# Selenium Webdriver not waiting for element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my selenium web driver initialization for firefox browser.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Even though I gave implicit wait selenium not waiting for the element. It is throwing the not found exception immediately. If I put `Thread.sleep` then it is working fine without any issues. But putting `Thread.sleep` everywhere the test case contains now more `Thread.sleep` than the actual test case code. Can anyone suggest me the right way to do this?

Comment: Why are you not using `ExplicitWait` instead using `WebDriverWait`??

Comment: although the preferred way is via explicit waits but above should work without any issue, are you able to replicate this issue on public url?

Comment: @MrunalGosar I tried the same without sleep in the public url. working fine. In my local it is throwing error

Comment: @MrunalGosar Even in the login page the button is getting clicked quickly but the action is not happening. If i put sleep for 5 sec, before click it is working fine. It is dojo.button

Comment: would u be able to put up a github project with sample application replicating your issue..else there is no other way of finding what is going wrong in your case

Answer (score 1):

in that case you should use `ExplicitWait` to wait for an specific element to be visible or present, because it's not a good practice tosleep the thread. I'll recommend to use:

```
WebDriver driver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, "time here");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)));
```